# Need a translator software application (without internet connection) that can tranlate english to hindi & vice versa

Tags: translation

Offline software is needed that can convert in various languages primarily  English to Hindi & vice versa in a ubuntu pc that does no have an internet connection.  We are ready to try, buy  & install that software for ubuntu.

Like, google translator that translates online in various languages, we need an offline translator.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 0):

Then you need a human being. Automated translation is new and not very reliable, and currently it needs large databases stored on remote servers to compare the text being translated with huge banks of similar text. This is not something a free standalone app can do.